# Python text file in string to dictionary

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to convert a text file into a dictionary in python.

The text file looks like this:

```
Age      Sex
------------
GT20      M
LT20      F
```

I want it to display as `(Age: GT20, LT20) (Sex: M,F)`
Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this in Python. Have you tried anything? If so, please show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

lines=[]
keys=[]
values=[]
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    lines=list(map(lambda line:line.strip(), f.readlines()))

d, flag={}, False
for line in lines:
    if re.match(r'^-+$', line):
        flag=True
        continue
    if flag:
        values.append(list(map(lambda x:x.strip(), line.split())))
    else:
        keys=list(map(lambda x:x.strip(), line.split()))

for i in range(len(keys)):
    d[keys[i]]=[value[i] for value in values]
print(d)
```

and here is the output:

```
$ cat data 
Age      Sex
------------
GT20      M
LT20      F
$ python3 p.py 
{'Sex': ['M', 'F'], 'Age': ['GT20', 'LT20']}
```